# PropertyGrid --> Select object from List<object>

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Is there a way to use a List like a selection-combobox in a propertyGrid?

For example, is it possible to have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [DisplayName(nameof(SelectedBar)),
    Browsable(true)]
    public Bar SelectedBar { get; set; } = null;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; } = new List<Bar>() { new Bar("Bar0"), new Bar("Bar1"), new Bar("Bar2") };
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name;

    public Bar(string name) { Name = name; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And in propertyGrid let me select one of the objects in the List of "Bar".

Comment: This would be much easier to handle using an Enum, why are you wanting to use a `List` here?

Comment: I need a solution for a List<object>, Enum doesn't fit to the problem

Comment: I think you are going to have to create a custom `UITypeEditor`, see [this MDSN walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ok i found the solution for it:

You need a derived converter class with a static object-list variable:

```
    public class ListStringConverter: StringConverter
    {
        public static List<object> Objects = new List<object>();

        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return new StandardValuesCollection(Objects);
        }
    }
```

And add a TypeConverter-Attribute with your converter to your selectedObject variable:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        ObjectListStringConverter.Objects = new List<object>(){ new Bar("Bar0"), new Bar("Bar1"), new Bar("Bar2") };
    }

    [DisplayName(nameof(SelectedBar)),
     Browsable(true),
     TypeConverter(typeof(ObjectListStringConverter))]
    public Bar SelectedBar { get; set; } = null;
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name;

    public Bar(string name) { Name = name; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And at some point you need to fill the static object-list variable of your converter-class with your objects you want to have in your list, like i did it in the Foo-Constructor above.

EDIT: The list will show the ToString() method return value of each object you added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer, but if you know what/how many objects you are using at compile time you could use an enum paired with a dictionary in the background.

```
public enum someEnum {name1, name2, name3}
Dictionary<someEnum, object> backEndDictionary = new Dictionary<someEnum, object>();
backEndDictionary[someEnum.name1] = object1;
...
```

And then just make sure you have a property using the enum on your property grid